# How best to override the authentication in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a project in which does not have registration. Administrator registers users in admin. The project does not have the roles, I have only one type of user. I do not need "AspNetRoles", "AspNetUserClaims", "AspNewUserLogins", "AspNetUserRoles". And in the table "AspNetUsers" I need only "Id", "Email", "Password" and a few custom properties. What is the best way to implement this in mvc 5?

Comment: I think removing these tables just for the sake of removing is a lot of extra work that brings no value to the project. As a project manager I'd say "leave them there, let them be, they ask no money to be".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Add more columns/fields to **AspNetUsers** you need to add those in Identity Model adn do Data Migration using `-update database` command

you can also control the Keys and Table Name by Overriding as below

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("MyUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("MyUsers").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("MyUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("MyUserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("MyUserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("MyRoles");
    }
```

When you are using ASPNET Schema for user registration, I don't think you can avoid Claims,Roles and other tables, but you can just ignore those.

### Update

In order to avoid Roles and Claims in ASPNET membership

First of all create a MVC 5 application. Then implement IUser,

```
public class ApplicationUser : IUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    public ApplicationUser(string userName): this()
    {
        UserName = userName;
    }
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Next we need a DbContet to store the Users,

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public virtual IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

and then we need to implement IUserStore, IUserPasswordStore and IUserSecurityStampStore,

```
public class MyUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserSecurityStampStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    UserStore<IdentityUser> userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
    public MyUserStore()
    {
    }
    public Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var context = userStore.Context as ApplicationDbContext;
        context.Users.Add(user);
        context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        return context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public Task DeleteAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var context = userStore.Context as ApplicationDbContext;
        context.Users.Remove(user);
        context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        return context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        var context = userStore.Context as ApplicationDbContext;
        return context.Users.Where(u => u.Id.ToLower() == userId.ToLower()).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
    public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        var context = userStore.Context as ApplicationDbContext;
        return context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == userName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
    public Task UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var context = userStore.Context as ApplicationDbContext;
        context.Users.Attach(user);
        context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        return context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        userStore.Dispose();
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(user);
        var task = userStore.GetPasswordHashAsync(identityUser);
        SetApplicationUser(user, identityUser);
        return task;
    }
    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(user);
        var task = userStore.HasPasswordAsync(identityUser);
        SetApplicationUser(user, identityUser);
        return task;
    }
    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(ApplicationUser user, string passwordHash)
    {
        var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(user);
        var task = userStore.SetPasswordHashAsync(identityUser, passwordHash);
        SetApplicationUser(user, identityUser);
        return task;
    }
    public Task<string> GetSecurityStampAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(user);
        var task = userStore.GetSecurityStampAsync(identityUser);
        SetApplicationUser(user, identityUser);
        return task;
    }
    public Task SetSecurityStampAsync(ApplicationUser user, string stamp)
    {
        var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(user);
        var task = userStore.SetSecurityStampAsync(identityUser, stamp);
        SetApplicationUser(user, identityUser);
        return task;
    }
    private static void SetApplicationUser(ApplicationUser user, IdentityUser identityUser)
    {
        user.PasswordHash = identityUser.PasswordHash;
        user.SecurityStamp = identityUser.SecurityStamp;
        user.Id = identityUser.Id;
        user.UserName = identityUser.UserName;
    }
    private IdentityUser ToIdentityUser(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return new IdentityUser
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            PasswordHash = user.PasswordHash,
            SecurityStamp = user.SecurityStamp,
            UserName = user.UserName
        };
    }
}
```

For password hash and security stamp, I am using the UserStore's implementation for making thing simpler. Finally we just need to change AccountController's constructor to leverage our MyUserStore implementation,

```
public AccountController()
    : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new MyUserStore()))
{
}

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
}
```

To Drop unnecessary columns in Users Table. You can try somethign like this

```
public partial class ModifyUser: DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "NewField", c => c.String());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "NewColumn");
    }
}
```

Then in packageManager run `PM> update-database`

Comment: @kriper Updated workaround to avoid Claims and Roles

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed description, but how to remove unnecessary fields in Identity 2.1? ApplicationUser implements IdentityUser.

Comment: @kriper you can try something like migration script I have updated in my answer